# not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown—block(0,0)

Tags: centos7

My VPS machine refuses to boot. There is an short error according to KVM console:

```
Kernel panic — not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown—block(0,0)
Pid: 1, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 #1
```

I can boot only with rescue mode (it's online VPS machine). I tried to follow similar topics but with no result.

Screen shot of full console errors down below:

[image]

Please let me know if I missed some extra info to resolve this problem.

This is CentOS 7, before my machine crashed (suddenly just hang up) I put those commands

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/selinux
SELINUX=disabled
```

(Which is already enabled again - no result)

```
systemctl enable iptables
systemctl start iptables
iptables -F
```

Followed by:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.200.024 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And then my machine hangs up for good.

Answer (score 1):

After connecting through rescue mode and doing `chroot` command (more or less like this: https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/25/t/69) I was able to launch

```
Yum update kernel
```

I'm pretty sure that was Grub2 fault because I was missing on one file from kernel in /boot/.

My server is up and running, but httpd service is still dead.
Thanks anyway community, greetings.

Answer (score 0):

It could be your /boot drive is full and you need to delete old kernels to free up space. There is an article how to do it in Ubuntu here https://jasoncoltrin.com/?p=1710 
Or pretty much you need to boot into advanced boot loader, boot with an older kernel, and then remove the old kernels.

Comment: your link doesn't work

Comment: sorry here you go https://jasoncoltrin.com/2017/01/13/fix-ubuntu-when-the-os-will-not-boot-kernel-panic-kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block-0-0-error-boot-full-remove-old-kernels-from-command-line/